# Rep too low to close vote? Flag it instead!

Tags: discussion, flagging, vote-to-close

Even if you haven't reached the [reputation level](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) required to visit the [review queue](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review), you can still give us a hand with pruning this wonderful resource if you wish to.

Flagging is a quick and easy mechanism for all users to highlight content that needs to be addressed by members with the rep requirements and inclination to do so.

See below for a brief description of how to flag, with screenshots.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A member with enough rep can click `flag`:

[image]

and choose the appropriate notification:

[image]

and it will go into the review Q for a higher rep member to vote on or a mod to look at it and decide.  When a decision is made you will also get credit.

Badeges are:

- [Citizen Patrol](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol): First flagged post
- [Deputy](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/deputy): Raise 80 helpful flags
- [Marshal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/72/marshal):  Raise 500 helpful flags

Comment: What credit do you get for flagging?

Comment: Badges either in the flavor of bronze, silver or GOLD..  GOLD!!!!

Comment: Ok that makes sense, knew I was missing something.

Comment: And who doesn't love GOLD!

Comment: Badeges, tricksy badeges... p.s. thanks to your gold-related enthusiasm I'm going to spend the rest of the day with Darth Vader singing [Spandau Ballet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSq8ZBdSxNU) stuck in my head. *I find your lack of belief in your soul disturbing...*

Comment: I do a fair amount of flagging (on other [SE] communities), and I sometimes get a warning like: "Your last flag was declined; are you sure you want to flag this?" Are there any consequences for having too many flags declined?